Изменение цвета трёх точек меню (java) мобильное приложение
Как поменять цвет точек меню при смене темы?
Меню создаётся так:
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

Есть такая функция для смены темы:
'''
private void setNaturalTheme() {

    // Установка природной темы
    companySpinner.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
    logoImageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green)); // Изменяем цвет фона для ImageView
    descriptionTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.brown));
    descriptionTextView.setTextSize(17);
    findViewById(R.id.activity_main).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green)); // Установка светло-зеленого фона
    descriptionTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // Выравнивание текста по центру
    
    updateSpinnerTheme(1);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Природная тема активирована", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

меню имеет следующую разметку
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/theme_light"
    android:title="Светлая тема" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/theme_natural"
    android:title="Природная тема" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/toggle_description"
    android:title="Описание"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:checked="true"/>


    Drawable drawable = toolbar.getOverflowIcon();
    if (drawable != null) {
        drawable.setColorFilter(
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
    }

